# Multiply lengths of all sub-lists in list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list made of an arbitrary number of sub-lists (meaning it is not fixed and can change in a different run of the code) I need to multiply the lengths of all sub-lists and obtain the final number.

Here's an MWE:

```
a = [[1.2,5.8,6,3], [1,48,5], [2.,3], [4,7,5.,2,5,3,6,554,6.,6,9], [6,.3,8,45.2,.001]]
n = 1
for sub_lst in a:
    n *= len(sub_lst)
print n
```

which results in `1320` since the lists have 4, 3, 2, 11 and 5 elements.

Is it possible to do this without resorting to a `for` loop? `numpy` answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using `for` at all, you need a lambda:

```
>>> a = [[1.2,5.8,6,3], [1,48,5], [2.,3], [4,7,5.,2,5,3,6,554,6.,6,9], [6,.3,8,45.2,.001]]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*len(y), a, 1)
1320
```

Or without lambda:

```
>>> reduce(operator.mul, map(len, a), 1)
```

Or using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.prod(map(len, a))
```

Comment: Selected since it can be used without extra packages. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This uses `reduce` and `operator.mul`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [[1.2,5.8,6,3], [1,48,5], [2.,3], [4,7,5.,2,5,3,6,554,6.,6,9], [6,.3,8,45.2,.001]]
>>> reduce(operator.mul, (len(l) for l in a), 1)
1320
```